# mysql query to fetch matching records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table_One

```
id name groupid
1  AAA   5,6
2  BBB   5,7
3  CCC   15
```

I am trying to make a query something like:

```
select * from Table_One 
where Table_One.groupid like '%".$objectData[groupid]."%'
```

such that if value of `$objectData[groupid]` is 5 then result should be

```
1  AAA   5,6
2  BBB   5,7
```

Similarly, if value of `$objectData[groupid]` is 6 then result should be

```
1  AAA   5,6
```

and, if value of `$objectData[groupid]` is 7 then result should be

```
2  BBB   5,7
```

Comment: Either use FIND_IN_SET instead of LIKE, or restructure your database and normalize your multiple group_ids into a separate relational table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `LIKE` use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html) function, try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_One 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(".$objectData[groupid].", Table_One.groupid);
```